# How do I fix this error in C# & LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I inserted the group by statement within a Linq query.  I know that because of this it will think it's an `IGrouping` type. The viewmodel is of type `IEnumerable`.

> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, myProject.Models.Link>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myProject.Models.Link>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
//The controller
LinkListViewModels model = new LinkListViewModels();

model.Links = (from p in db.Links
               group p by p.category_name into g
               select g);
return View(model);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of grouping here? which items from each category name you want to get?

Comment: Why are you grouping them?  What result do you expect?  Maybe you actually wanted an order by?  In general you'll have to do something like `select g.First()` if you just want the first item of each group.

Comment: And can you share your viewModel LinkListViewModels

Comment: Grouping is generic type with two type parameters, the key and the type of the value in a collection. That's why the cast doesn't work.

Comment: I want to group by category_name, so i only get one result from each category and not duplicate content. I don't think order by would do the magic here  in this case.

Comment: `I know that because of this it will think it's an IGrouping type. The viewmodel is of type IEnumerable.` So since you know the exact source of your problem, why ask the question?  You know what the problem is, and what you did to cause it.

Comment: I know that because of adding the `GroupBy` it will think it is an `IGrouping` type. It doesn't _think_ it is that type, it _**is**_ that type. You made it that way by changing the action on it. If you want to move it back to the `IEnumerable`, then you need to do another action on it to switch it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says that type of LINQ query does not match type of property `Links`. It's a EF query, which has `IQueryable<T>` type. And items of this query are groups with string keys: `IGrouping<string, myProject.Models.Link>`. On the other hand property is simple list of `Link` models. So, you need to do two things:

1. Get model(s) from each group
2. Save query results to list

Sample code which selects first item from each group:

```
model.Links = (from p in db.Links
               group p by p.category_name into g
               select g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

I personally don't like mixing query and method syntax. So here is same query in method syntax:

```
model.Links = db.Links.GroupBy(l => l.category_name)
                      .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this worked with the little change FirstOrDefault instead of First. So i ended up with: 

    model.Links = (from p in db.Links
    group p by p.category_name into g
    select g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Comment: @neo my bad, I forgot that EF don't support `First()` but don't worry - you will always have an item, there will not be *default* case

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be following:

```
LinkListViewModels model = new LinkListViewModels();

model.Links = (from p in db.Links
               group p by p.category_name into g
               select g).SelectMany(g => g.Take(1)).ToList();
return View(model);
```

Comment: There is not `Top` method in Linq, I guess you meant `First` and you don't want the `SelectMany` for that just apply it directly to `g` as in `select g.First()`

Comment: @juharr It should be Take then, I am not a compile. And First will give you an compile time error.

Comment: Because I use SelectMany method whose lambda should return collection.

Comment: What you have now will work, but like I said a simple `select g.First()` will be simpler than the `SelectMany` and `Take`.

Comment: You are right, that's what @Sergey Berezovskiy shows in his answer.